# PHP Search FTP for certain File by extension and Download it

Tags: php, file, download, ftp

i'm stuck with a Project i'm currently working on.

I have to make a PHP Script that uploads a File to a specific FTP, the file gets processed by another script which is observing the FTP on the Fly. After the processing is done a new File is generated with one of 4 possible file extensions and the original file gets deleted automaticly. Here's where my Problem starts, i'm not that much into PHP for i'm working with it far too rarely.

So i have to search for the file with one of the four possible Extensions and download it to the machine where the PHP Script is running on and the search needs to be done by this PHP Script. Any suggestions how to achieve this for i have not a glimps of a clue :(

Comment: how would that help me with the problem that everything needs to be done by the PHP Script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not search through FTP protocol.

You have to list a directory and then search for desired file(s) locally:

```
$ftp = ftp_connect( $ftpHost );
ftp_login( $ftp, $ftpUsername, $ftpPassword ) or die( 'Oh No!' );
$files = ftp_nlist( $ftp, 'www/myDir' );
$filteredFiles = preg_grep( '/\.php$/i', $files );
ftp_close($ftp);
```

With above example all the files in `www/Dir` directory with `.php` extension are now in `$filteredFiles` array.

#### Alternatives:

- If your remote server allow SSH2 connection, you can retrieve the files list through a [SSH2 connection](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.ssh2.php);
- If your remote server is php/HTTP enabled, you can write a php script on remote server to search file(s) and then perform an HTTP request.